# using buttons to enter text in textarea, want each entry to start on a new line

Tags: javascript, input, textarea, newline

I have a simple webpage I created for work purposes.  It has multiple buttons that enter text into a text area.  I would like every input to start on a new line.  I have tried entering /r /n in every place I could think of but can't seem to get it to work. Couldn't seem to find the exact answer in any other posts. Here are the relevant parts of the code.

```js
function insertText(val,e){
    document.getElementById(e).innerHTML+=val;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:insertText('Application submitted by applicant - Demande          Presentee par requerant \n','textarea');" onClick="void(0)">[sub by appl]</a>
<a href="javascript:insertText('Application submitted by a third party - Demande presentee par une tierce partie : ','textarea');" onClick="void(0)">[sub by 3rd party]</a>

<form name="textform">
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"> 
        <textarea name="textarea" cols="100" rows="15">
        </textarea>
    </font> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass an elements id to `getElementById`  there is no element with id `textarea` if you want to select the textarea that way give it an id `<textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" cols="100" rows="15">`

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to use **innerHTML** property to set the value of textarea, but use its **value** property.

2) Better practice is to use **href** attribute with **"#"** value and in **onclick** set event handler which returns **false**.

3) **data-*** attributes are very useful. You can validly store any information in tag using this approach:

```
<div id="person-27" data-name="Linus" data-surname="Torvalds">Linux creator</div>
```

...and later retrieve this information like you can see in example below.

4) Use **\n** to insert new line.

So your code can look like:

```
<a class="text-btn" href="#"
    data-text="Application submitted by applicant - Demande Presentee par requerant">
    [sub by appl]
</a>

<a class="text-btn" href="#"
    data-text="Application submitted by a third party - Demande presentee par une tierce partie">
    [sub by 3rd party]
</a>

<form name="textform" id="textform">
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"> 
        <textarea name="textarea" cols="100" rows="15"></textarea>
    </font> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var form = document.getElementById('textform'),
            textarea = form['textarea'],
            anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        function insertText() {
            textarea.value += this.getAttribute('data-text') + "\n";
            return false;
        }
        for(var i = 0, l = anchors.length; i < l; i++) {
            if(anchors[i].className == 'text-btn') {
                anchors[i].onclick = insertText;
            }
        }
    })();
</script>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/EYf5g/)